# Do you need exchange ICE candidates for TCP connection

Tags: stun, sdp, turn, ice

A user A wants to send TCP request to user B over ICE/TURN/STUN mechanism. If user B generates a SDP with its ICE candidates and send it to user A. Is user A must answer directly to user B without to send its SDP and ICE candidates to user B?
We only want TCP connection (no UDP).

Indeed, when user A receives SDP of user B with ICE candidates of user B. It can to initiate checks in order to know which IP of user B it can use to create a TCP connection (so send stun request to user B for each IP).
When the TCP connection is opened. USER A send request to user B and B can response to this request over TCP, no?
User B no need to check which IP of A that it can to contact because it doesn't need to send request to user A, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing P2P NAT traversal over TCP is a bit harder than UDP.  But yes, it requires exchanging candidate addresses, including the public address obtained from a STUN or TURN server.  And the main trick is often that both endpoints need to try connecting to each other at the same time.

Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching

Comment: Thanks, but my question is if I just need send an TCP request from User A to User B, do we need that User A send its ice candidates to User B. When user A receives ice candidates of user B. It can establish a connection and send a TCP request to B (and receive TCP response) , no? Or for TCP response User B need to establish a connection to user A?

Comment: Yes.  Because in order to do TCP NAT traversal effectively, both A and B need to connect at the same time.  Also, there will be situations were A can't connect to B, but B can connect to A.  Hence, you need to be trying in both directions.